# KORG TRITON LE, can I make my own sounds?

Tags: synthesizer

All I see are presets, is that all i can use? Can I make my own sounds with it? I mean I look at the moog and its got like 30 knobbys for tweaking.

Comment: @WheatWilliams Synthesizer programming is as relevant to musical practice and performance as string tuning, string types and characteristics, instrument materials, etc. "Synthesizer programming, and the particular capabilities of a certain model of synthesizer" have everything to do with both musical performance and musical practice. He doesn't need to find another forum, his question is on topic.

Comment: @WheatWilliams That's a whole different point. I think the existence of manuals is irrelevant. Most of the questions on this site have been answered somewhere else: manuals, books, tutorials, wikis, whatever. We are not supposed to tell everyone that the question has been answered somewhere else and go to find another forum. This is a Q&A site! The only duplicates relevant to us are the duplicates on this site. We are an alternative, a complement, to a manual, to a book, to a wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM: [old triton manuals](http://www.iub.edu/~emusic/361-old/triton_manuals.htm) -- on page 23 (or so) it describes how the knobs can be used to modify the existing sound samples in a manner similar to an analog synth.

For completely customization, you'd want to use the sampling features: i.e. play the sounds that you want into the audio input and then assign them to keys.

Comment: Okay, I'll buy the sampling pack. also Should i get one of those smart media cards for patches?

Comment: If you can; the hardware format is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page below, you'll find guides and manuals in pdf, they should provide the answer.
http://www.korg.co.uk/support/downloads/tritonle_dl.php